# accessing local website from another PC with codeigniter

Tags: apache, codeigniter, xampp

I install my website with codeigniter; I am unable to access to my website from another computer,
for example:
for access to local server is http://127.0.0.1:81/website and address of the machine is 192.168.1.1

I enter the address of the machine where website is installed like this
192.168.1.1:81/website, and it redirects me to the http://127.0.0.1:81/website

local server is xampp

Help!!!! please

Sorry for english!

Comment: You can get your local server from your machine only not from other computers.

Comment: You have to set the `base_url` as `http://192.168.1.1/website/` in your `application/config.php` when you access from other systems.

Comment: thank you it's work perfectly